# WMI Association of LogicalDisk with DiskPartition

Tags: c#, .net, wmi, systemmanagement

I am trying to put together a list which shows all LogicalDisk instances in my Computer System and the drive letters they have been associated with. Coding is in C#.

The WMI classes **Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition**, **Win32_DiskPartition** and **Win32_LogicalDisk** appeared to be the right data sources to get that Job done:

- **Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition** contains the property "*Antecedent*" which obviously links to a "*DeviceId*" property of class **Win32_DiskPartition**
- and **Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition** contains the property "*Dependent*" which obviously links to a "*DeviceId*" property of class **Win32_LogicalDisk**

And here's my problem:

The *Antecedent* property of **Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition** returns a string value like:

```
\\\\HOME-PC\\root\\cimv2:Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID=\"Disk #2, Partition #0\
```

but I need only `Disk #2, Partition #0` to match it with the *DeviceId* property values of class **Win32_DiskPartition**.

Similar Problem with the Dependent property value.

Is there a way to obtain this substring (except by hard coded string parsing)?

I am afraid a query does not help because I do also need additional information about the logical disk and the associated disk Partition. I am aware that I have to cover Extended partitions with multiple drive letters - this can be done with the *StartingAddress* property of the **Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition** instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This type of enumeration is usually performed using `System.Management`'s
[ManagementObjectSearcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementobjectsearcher) building the query using the WQL [ASSOCIATORS OF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/associators-of-statement) Statement
This is one sequential path you can follow to retrieve information on drives in a system:

> Enumerate the Disk Drives => For Each [DeviceID] =>
> Enumerate Disk Drive to Partition => For Each [DeviceID]
> Enumerate Logical Disk to Partition

Objects in each class have their associated properties:

[Disk Drives (MSDN)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-diskdrive)
[Partition (MSDN)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-logicaldisktopartition)
[Logical Disk (MSDN)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-logicaldisk)

```
using System.Management;

 //Define an initial scope for the following queries
 var scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + Environment.MachineName + @"\root\CIMV2");

 //Select all Disk Drives
 var query = new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");
 //Options => Timeout infinite to avoid timeouts and forward only for speed
 var options = new EnumerationOptions();
 options.Timeout = EnumerationOptions.InfiniteTimeout;
 options.Rewindable = false;
 options.ReturnImmediately = true;

 //New root Management Object
 var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query, options);

 //Enumerate all Disk Drives
 foreach (ManagementObject moDisk in searcher.Get())
 {
    //Query the associated partitions of the current DeviceID
    string assocQuery = "Associators of {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID='" + 
                        mobDisk.Properties["DeviceID"].Value.ToString() + "'}" +
                        "where AssocClass=Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition";
    var assocPart = new ManagementObjectSearcher(assocQuery);
    assocPart.Options.Timeout = EnumerationOptions.InfiniteTimeout;

    //For each Disk Drive, query the associated partitions
    foreach (ManagementObject moPart in assocPart.Get())
    {
       Console.WriteLine("DeviceID: {0}  BootPartition: {1}", 
                         moPart.Properties["DeviceID"].Value.ToString(), 
                         moPart.Properties["BootPartition"].Value.ToString());

       //Query the associated logical disk of the current PartitionID
       string logDiskQuery = "Associators of {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID='" + 
                              moPart.Properties["DeviceID"].Value.ToString() + "'} " +
                              "where AssocClass=Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition";

       var logDisk = new ManagementObjectSearcher(logDiskQuery);
       logDisk.Options.Timeout = EnumerationOptions.InfiniteTimeout;

       //For each partition, query the Logical Drives
       foreach (var logDiskEnu in logDisk.Get())
       {
          Console.WriteLine("Volume Name: {0}  Serial Number: {1}  System Name: {2}",
                            logDiskEnu.Properties["VolumeName"].Value.ToString(),
                            logDiskEnu.Properties["VolumeSerialNumber"].Value.ToString(),
                            logDiskEnu.Properties["SystemName"].Value.ToString());
          Console.WriteLine("Description: {0}  DriveType: {1}  MediaType: {2}",
                            logDiskEnu.Properties["Description"].Value.ToString(),
                            logDiskEnu.Properties["DriveType"].Value.ToString(),
                            logDiskEnu.Properties["MediaType"].Value.ToString());
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort with providing the code example. I get now (almost) all Information I want. Your Response made it evident that I should look into WMI scripting.

Comment: very nice answer. thanks. but how can I get Partition FreeSpace?

Comment: @Mahmood Jenami Get the *bigger guy*: [Get the serial number of USB storage devices in .Net Core 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51806262/7444103). Per Partition, you have a `List<LogicalDisk>` and for each `LogicalDisk` there's a `FreeSpace` property value (ulong). By chance, I've just modified that class. If you use it and find a bug, let me know.