# How to capture USB Eject event in C# console application

Tags: c#, usb

### What I want to achieve

I have a console application that runs a file system watcher for USB drives.
When I try to eject device, I receive prompt message notifying device is in use.
**I want to capture that request, close the file system watcher and resume the USB eject process**.
I don't want eject notification (i.e; Event fired after USB is removed).

### What I've tried

I've Tried These [Method 1](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18062/Detecting-USB-Drive-Removal-in-a-C-Program)
[Method 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2988572/10383699)
[Method 3](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32026/Capturing-Device-Events-in-a-C-Windows-Service)

The method 1 is a winform application, it works but It would be great if I could do it in a Console application.

In method 2 event is fired only after USB is removed, but I want to capture the event before it is ejected.

Method 3 is a windows service application, I can't get the DriveID (eg: F) in this.

Sorry for any mistakes. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi take a look at the following SO answer. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52598371/catch-usb-plug-and-unplug-event-system-invalidcastexception?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: @TerblancheDaniel Thanks for the response, I've tried this in [Method 1](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18062/Detecting-USB-Drive-Removal-in-a-C-Program) and it works, I was hoping to do the same in a console application where I don't have a Message Handler (WinForms) or Service Handler (WinService) which is needed to  use the RegisterDeviceNotification