# How do I get information about recently connected USB device?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, wmi, systemmanagement

I can catch when usb device is connected with  [Win32_DeviceChangeEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-devicechangeevent)

but there are only 3 properties allowed to view

```
class Win32_DeviceChangeEvent : __ExtrinsicEvent
{
  uint8  SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR[];
  uint64 TIME_CREATED;
  uint16 EventType;
};
```

But i don't understand how to get **all** info about this device. Specifically, its **port and hub, VirtualHubAdress Name** and etc.

```
public enum EventType
{
    Inserted = 2,
    Removed = 3
}

public static void RegisterUsbDeviceNotification()
{
    var watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher();
    var query = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_DeviceChangeEvent WHERE EventType = 2");
    //watcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(watcher_EventArrived);
    watcher.EventArrived += (s, e) =>
    {
        //here is im need to get info about this device

        EventType eventType = (EventType)(Convert.ToInt16(e.NewEvent.Properties["EventType"].Value));
    };

    watcher.Query = query;
    watcher.Start();
}
```

maybe i can do it with using smth like this

```
[DllImport("UseFull.dll")] 
private IntpPtr GetAllinfo(params);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Win32_DeviceChangeEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-devicechangeevent) reports just the type of event that occurred and the Time of the event (uint64, representing 100-nanosecond intervals after January 1, 1601, UTC). No that much useful if you also want to know what arrived or was removed.

I suggest to use instead the [WqlEventQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.wqleventquery) class, setting its [EventClassName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.wqleventquery.eventclassname) to [__InstanceOperationEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementbaseobject).
This system class provides a **`TargetInstance`** property the can be cast to a [ManagementBaseObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementbaseobject), the full management object that also provides base information on the Device that generated the event.
This information includes (besides the friendly name of the Device) the **`PNPDeviceID`**, which can be used to build other queries to further inspect the Device referenced.

The `WqlEventQuery`'s [Condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.wqleventquery.condition) property can be set here to `TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_DiskDrive'`.
It can be set to any other `Win32_` class of interest.

Setup the event listener (local machine):
(The event handler is called **`DeviceChangedEvent`**)

```
var query = new WqlEventQuery() {
    EventClassName = "__InstanceOperationEvent",
    WithinInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3),
    Condition = @"TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_DiskDrive'"
};

var scope = new ManagementScope("root\\CIMV2");
using (var moWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(scope, query))
{
    moWatcher.Options.Timeout = ManagementOptions.InfiniteTimeout;
    moWatcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(DeviceChangedEvent);
    moWatcher.Start();
}
```

The event handler receives, in `e.NewEvent.Properties["TargetInstance"]`, the Management Object representing a [Win32_DiskDrive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-diskdrive) class.
See the Docs about the properties directly available here.

The `__InstanceOperationEvent` derived classes of interest, reported by the `e.NewEvent.ClassPath.ClassName`, can be:

[__InstanceCreationEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WmiSdk/--instancecreationevent):  A new Device arrival has been detected.
[__InstanceDeletionEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WmiSdk/--instancedeletionevent):  A Device removal has been detected.
[__InstanceModificationEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WmiSdk/--instancemodificationevent): An existing device has been modified in some way.

Note that the event is raised in a secondary thread, we need to `BeginInvoke()` the UI thread to update the UI with the new information.
▶ You should avoid `Invoke()` here, because it's synchronous: it will block the handler until the method completes. Also, in this context, a dead-lock is not exactly a remote possibility.

See here: [Get serial number of USB storage device](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51806262/7444103) for a class that provides most of the information available about a device (the information is filtered to show USB devices only, but the filter can be removed).

```
private void DeviceChangedEvent(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    using (var moBase = (ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent.Properties["TargetInstance"].Value)
    {
        string oInterfaceType = moBase?.Properties["InterfaceType"]?.Value.ToString();
        string devicePNPId = moBase?.Properties["PNPDeviceID"]?.Value.ToString();
        string deviceDescription = moBase?.Properties["Caption"]?.Value.ToString();
        string eventMessage = $"{oInterfaceType}: {deviceDescription} ";

        switch (e.NewEvent.ClassPath.ClassName)
        {
            case "__InstanceDeletionEvent":
                eventMessage += " removed";
                break;
            case "__InstanceCreationEvent":
                eventMessage += "inserted";
                break;
            case "__InstanceModificationEvent":
            default:
                eventMessage += $" {e.NewEvent.ClassPath.ClassName}";
                break;
        }
        BeginInvoke(new Action(() => UpdateUI(eventMessage)));
    }
}

private void UpdateUI(string message)
{
   //Update the UI controls with information provided by the event
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Win32_PnPEntity to get details. [Win32_PnPEntity class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-pnpentity)

Comment: How do i get for example deviceId from Win32_DeviceChangeEvent to make request for Win32_PnPEntity ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ORMi](https://github.com/nicoriff/ORMi) to create a watcher so you can get information about any new device:

```
WMIHelper helper = new WMIHelper("root\\CimV2");

WMIWatcher watcher = new WMIWatcher("root\\CimV2", "SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_PnPEntity'");
watcher.WMIEventArrived += Watcher_WMIEventArrived;
```

And then you can watch for the events:

```
private static void Watcher_WMIEventArrived(object sender, WMIEventArgs e)
{
    //DO YOUR WORK
}
```