# How can I listen for Device Changes in .NET Core. (Need Substitute for WindowsForms NativeWindow class)

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, .net-core

I have a .NET Framework application that I am migrating to .NET Core.  It has gone very smoothly but there is one class I need to find a substitute for.

I need to know when a user plugs a USB device into the computer so I can test if it's one of my company's devices and update my UI appropriately.  In .NET Framework 4.8  I used the `System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow` class to listen for `WM_DEVICECHANGE` messages.  It worked great:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public sealed class DeviceChangeListener : NativeWindow
{
    public event EventHandler<IntPtr> DeviceChanged;

    public DeviceChangeListener() => CreateHandle(new CreateParams());

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_DEVICECHANGE)
            DeviceChanged?.Invoke(this, m.WParam);

        base.WndProc(ref m); // don't forget this line
    }

    public static readonly int    WM_DEVICECHANGE             = 0x0219;              //see msdn site
}
```

Unfortunately, I don't seem to have access to this on .NET core (nor would I expect to), but I would like to find a substitute.

How might I go about replicating this functionality on .NET Core?  I'm OK with a Windows-specific approach because for the time being, I'm still going to be on Windows.

-Joe

Comment: [How do i get info about recently connected usb device](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54298316/7444103)

Comment: Get detailed informations about a USB storage device: [Get serial number of USB storage device in .net core 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51806262/7444103)

Comment: I appreciate the effort but I am not trying to find out information about a plugged-in -device.  I am trying to be notified ***when the device is plugged in***

EDIT: Ok, Jimi I responded too quickly.  I now see the part about the event.  I can and will use WMI if need be.  If anyone has an idea for a slighly less-heavy approach (I've used WMI before) I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: About the WMI event watcher, the *heavy approach* (if you want to call it that) has already been taken care of and there's enough info there to understand what's going on; you just need to copy/paste that code and you're done. The other part, the information-gatherer class, is a plus, in case you need it (it's also the copy/paste/done kind and it all stays in the WMI *family*).

Comment: The drawback is that is not really portable for now. The *NIX implementation version of the CIMV2 classes is not going well...

Comment: @Jimi I am in the fortunate position of being able to wait for that.  Frankly I would have been happy to stay on .NET Framework 4.8 but that would have prevented me from upgrading my EF Core NuGet packages to the latest versions, since the EF Core abandoned .NET FW going forward