# Display automatically values in textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, cardreader

I use one method that returns a value in a textbox to the click button. Is it possible to automatically call this method somehow? And whenever it returns a value to display the same in a textbox without using the button.

```
     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (connectCard())
                {
                    string cardUID = getcardUID();
                    textBox1.Text = cardUID; //displaying on textbox
                }
            }
            private string getcardUID()//only for mifare 1k cards
                {
                    string cardUID = "";
                    byte[] receivedUID = new byte[256];
                    Card.SCARD_IO_REQUEST request = new Card.SCARD_IO_REQUEST();
                    request.dwProtocol = Card.SCARD_PROTOCOL_T1;
                    request.cbPciLength = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Card.SCARD_IO_REQUEST));
                    byte[] sendBytes = new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xCA, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }; //get UID command      for Mifare cards
                    int outBytes = receivedUID.Length;
                    int status = Card.SCardTransmit(hCard, ref request, ref sendBytes[0], sendBytes.Length, ref request, ref receivedUID[0], ref outBytes);

                    if (status != Card.SCARD_S_SUCCESS)
                    {
                        cardUID = "Error";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cardUID = BitConverter.ToString(receivedUID.Take(4).ToArray()).Replace("-", string.Empty).ToLower();
                    }

                    return cardUID;
                }

     public class Card
        {
            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            public struct SCARD_IO_REQUEST
            {
                public int dwProtocol;
                public int cbPciLength;
            }

            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            public struct APDURec
            {
                public byte bCLA;
                public byte bINS;
                public byte bP1;
                public byte bP2;
                public byte bP3;
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 256)]
                public byte[] Data;
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
                public byte[] SW;
                public bool IsSend;
            }

            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            public struct SCARD_READERSTATE
            {
                public string RdrName;
                public int UserData;
                public int RdrCurrState;
                public int RdrEventState;
                public int ATRLength;
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 37)]
                public byte[] ATRValue;
            }

            public const int SCARD_S_SUCCESS = 0;
            public const int SCARD_ATR_LENGTH = 33;


            /* ===========================================================
            '  Memory Card type constants
            '===========================================================*/
            public const int CT_MCU = 0x00;                   // MCU
            public const int CT_IIC_Auto = 0x01;               // IIC (Auto Detect Memory Size)
            public const int CT_IIC_1K = 0x02;                 // IIC (1K)
            public const int CT_IIC_2K = 0x03;                 // IIC (2K)
            public const int CT_IIC_4K = 0x04;                 // IIC (4K)
            public const int CT_IIC_8K = 0x05;                 // IIC (8K)
            public const int CT_IIC_16K = 0x06;                // IIC (16K)
            public const int CT_IIC_32K = 0x07;                // IIC (32K)
            public const int CT_IIC_64K = 0x08;                // IIC (64K)
            public const int CT_IIC_128K = 0x09;               // IIC (128K)
            public const int CT_IIC_256K = 0x0A;               // IIC (256K)
            public const int CT_IIC_512K = 0x0B;               // IIC (512K)
            public const int CT_IIC_1024K = 0x0C;              // IIC (1024K)
            public const int CT_AT88SC153 = 0x0D;              // AT88SC153
            public const int CT_AT88SC1608 = 0x0E;             // AT88SC1608
            public const int CT_SLE4418 = 0x0F;                // SLE4418
            public const int CT_SLE4428 = 0x10;                // SLE4428
            public const int CT_SLE4432 = 0x11;                // SLE4432
            public const int CT_SLE4442 = 0x12;                // SLE4442
            public const int CT_SLE4406 = 0x13;                // SLE4406
            public const int CT_SLE4436 = 0x14;                // SLE4436
            public const int CT_SLE5536 = 0x15;                // SLE5536
            public const int CT_MCUT0 = 0x16;                  // MCU T=0
            public const int CT_MCUT1 = 0x17;                  // MCU T=1
            public const int CT_MCU_Auto = 0x18;               // MCU Autodetect

            /*===============================================================
            ' CONTEXT SCOPE
            =============================================================== */
            public const int SCARD_SCOPE_USER = 0;
            /*===============================================================
            ' The context is a user context, and any database operations 
            '  are performed within the domain of the user.
            '===============================================================*/
            public const int SCARD_SCOPE_TERMINAL = 1;
            /*===============================================================
            ' The context is that of the current terminal, and any database 
            'operations are performed within the domain of that terminal.  
            '(The calling application must have appropriate access permissions 
            'for any database actions.)
            '===============================================================*/

            public const int SCARD_SCOPE_SYSTEM = 2;
            /*===============================================================
            ' The context is the system context, and any database operations 
            ' are performed within the domain of the system.  (The calling
            ' application must have appropriate access permissions for any 
            ' database actions.)
            '===============================================================*/
            /*=============================================================== 
            ' Context Scope
            '===============================================================*/
            public const int SCARD_STATE_UNAWARE = 0x00;
            /*===============================================================
            ' The application is unaware of the current state, and would like 
            ' to know. The use of this value results in an immediate return
            ' from state transition monitoring services. This is represented
            ' by all bits set to zero.
            '===============================================================*/
            public const int SCARD_STATE_IGNORE = 0x01;
            /*===============================================================
            ' The application requested that this reader be ignored. No other
            ' bits will be set.
            '===============================================================*/

            public const int SCARD_STATE_CHANGED = 0x02;
            /*===============================================================
            ' This implies that there is a difference between the state 
            ' believed by the application, and the state known by the Service
            ' Manager.When this bit is set, the application may assume a
            ' significant state change has occurred on this reader.
            '===============================================================*/

            public const int SCARD_STATE_UNKNOWN = 0x04;
            /*===============================================================
            ' This implies that the given reader name is not recognized by
            ' the Service Manager. If this bit is set, then SCARD_STATE_CHANGED
            ' and SCARD_STATE_IGNORE will also be set.
            '===============================================================*/
            public const int SCARD_STATE_UNAVAILABLE = 0x08;
            /*===============================================================
            ' This implies that the actual state of this reader is not
            ' available. If this bit is set, then all the following bits are
            ' clear.
            '===============================================================*/
            public const int SCARD_STATE_EMPTY = 0x10;
            /*===============================================================
            '  This implies that there is not card in the reader.  If this bit
            '  is set, all the following bits will be clear.
             ===============================================================*/
            public const int SCARD_STATE_PRESENT = 0x20;
            /*===============================================================
            '  This implies that there is a card in the reader.
             ===============================================================*/
            public const int SCARD_STATE_ATRMATCH = 0x40;
            /*===============================================================
            '  This implies that there is a card in the reader with an ATR
            '  matching one of the target cards. If this bit is set,
            '  SCARD_STATE_PRESENT will also be set.  This bit is only returned
            '  on the SCardLocateCard() service.
             ===============================================================*/
            public const int SCARD_STATE_EXCLUSIVE = 0x80;
            /*===============================================================
            '  This implies that the card in the reader is allocated for 
            '  exclusive use by another application. If this bit is set,
            '  SCARD_STATE_PRESENT will also be set.
             ===============================================================*/
            public const int SCARD_STATE_INUSE = 0x100;
            /*===============================================================
            '  This implies that the card in the reader is in use by one or 
            '  more other applications, but may be connected to in shared mode. 
            '  If this bit is set, SCARD_STATE_PRESENT will also be set.
             ===============================================================*/
            public const int SCARD_STATE_MUTE = 0x200;
            /*===============================================================
            '  This implies that the card in the reader is unresponsive or not
            '  supported by the reader or software.
            ' ===============================================================*/
            public const int SCARD_STATE_UNPOWERED = 0x400;
            /*===============================================================
            '  This implies that the card in the reader has not been powered up.
            ' ===============================================================*/

            public const int SCARD_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE = 1;
            /*===============================================================
            ' This application is not willing to share this card with other 
            'applications.
            '===============================================================*/
            public const int SCARD_SHARE_SHARED = 2;
            /*===============================================================
            ' This application is willing to share this card with other 
            'applications.
            '===============================================================*/
            public const int SCARD_SHARE_DIRECT = 3;
            /*===============================================================
            ' This application demands direct control of the reader, so it 
            ' is not available to other applications.
            '===============================================================*/

            /*===========================================================
            '   Disposition
            '===========================================================*/
            public const int SCARD_LEAVE_CARD = 0;   // Don't do anything special on close
            public const int SCARD_RESET_CARD = 1;   // Reset the card on close
            public const int SCARD_UNPOWER_CARD = 2;   // Power down the card on close
            public const int SCARD_EJECT_CARD = 3;   // Eject the card on close


            /* ===========================================================
            ' ACS IOCTL class
            '===========================================================*/
            public const long FILE_DEVICE_SMARTCARD = 0x310000; // Reader action IOCTLs

            public const long IOCTL_SMARTCARD_DIRECT = FILE_DEVICE_SMARTCARD + 2050 * 4;
            public const long IOCTL_SMARTCARD_SELECT_SLOT = FILE_DEVICE_SMARTCARD + 2051 * 4;
            public const long IOCTL_SMARTCARD_DRAW_LCDBMP = FILE_DEVICE_SMARTCARD + 2052 * 4;
            public const long IOCTL_SMARTCARD_DISPLAY_LCD = FILE_DEVICE_SMARTCARD + 2053 * 4;
            public const long IOCTL_SMARTCARD_CLR_LCD = FILE_DEVICE_SMARTCARD + 2054 * 4;
            public const long IOCTL_SMARTCARD_READ_KEYPAD = FILE_DEVICE_SMARTCARD + 2055 * 4;
            public const long IOCTL_SMARTCARD_READ_RTC = FILE_DEVICE_SMARTCARD + 2057 * 4;
            public const long IOCTL_SMARTCARD_SET_RTC = FILE_DEVICE_SMARTCARD + 2058 * 4;
            public const long IOCTL_SMARTCARD_SET_OPTION = FILE_DEVICE_SMARTCARD + 2059 * 4;
            public const long IOCTL_SMARTCARD_SET_LED = FILE_DEVICE_SMARTCARD + 2060 * 4;
            public const long IOCTL_SMARTCARD_LOAD_KEY = FILE_DEVICE_SMARTCARD + 2062 * 4;
            public const long IOCTL_SMARTCARD_READ_EEPROM = FILE_DEVICE_SMARTCARD + 2065 * 4;
            public const long IOCTL_SMARTCARD_WRITE_EEPROM = FILE_DEVICE_SMARTCARD + 2066 * 4;
            public const long IOCTL_SMARTCARD_GET_VERSION = FILE_DEVICE_SMARTCARD + 2067 * 4;
            public const long IOCTL_SMARTCARD_GET_READER_INFO = FILE_DEVICE_SMARTCARD + 2051 * 4;
            public const long IOCTL_SMARTCARD_SET_CARD_TYPE = FILE_DEVICE_SMARTCARD + 2060 * 4;
            public const long IOCTL_SMARTCARD_ACR128_ESCAPE_COMMAND = FILE_DEVICE_SMARTCARD + 2079 * 4;

            /*===========================================================
            '   Error Codes
            '===========================================================*/
            public const int SCARD_F_INTERNAL_ERROR = -2146435071;
            public const int SCARD_E_CANCELLED = -2146435070;
            public const int SCARD_E_INVALID_HANDLE = -2146435069;
            public const int SCARD_E_INVALID_PARAMETER = -2146435068;
            public const int SCARD_E_INVALID_TARGET = -2146435067;
            public const int SCARD_E_NO_MEMORY = -2146435066;
            public const int SCARD_F_WAITED_TOO_LONG = -2146435065;
            public const int SCARD_E_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER = -2146435064;
            public const int SCARD_E_UNKNOWN_READER = -2146435063;


            public const int SCARD_E_TIMEOUT = -2146435062;
            public const int SCARD_E_SHARING_VIOLATION = -2146435061;
            public const int SCARD_E_NO_SMARTCARD = -2146435060;
            public const int SCARD_E_UNKNOWN_CARD = -2146435059;
            public const int SCARD_E_CANT_DISPOSE = -2146435058;
            public const int SCARD_E_PROTO_MISMATCH = -2146435057;


            public const int SCARD_E_NOT_READY = -2146435056;
            public const int SCARD_E_INVALID_VALUE = -2146435055;
            public const int SCARD_E_SYSTEM_CANCELLED = -2146435054;
            public const int SCARD_F_COMM_ERROR = -2146435053;
            public const int SCARD_F_UNKNOWN_ERROR = -2146435052;
            public const int SCARD_E_INVALID_ATR = -2146435051;
            public const int SCARD_E_NOT_TRANSACTED = -2146435050;
            public const int SCARD_E_READER_UNAVAILABLE = -2146435049;
            public const int SCARD_P_SHUTDOWN = -2146435048;
            public const int SCARD_E_PCI_TOO_SMALL = -2146435047;

            public const int SCARD_E_READER_UNSUPPORTED = -2146435046;
            public const int SCARD_E_DUPLICATE_READER = -2146435045;
            public const int SCARD_E_CARD_UNSUPPORTED = -2146435044;
            public const int SCARD_E_NO_SERVICE = -2146435043;
            public const int SCARD_E_SERVICE_STOPPED = -2146435042;

            public const int SCARD_W_UNSUPPORTED_CARD = -2146435041;
            public const int SCARD_W_UNRESPONSIVE_CARD = -2146435040;
            public const int SCARD_W_UNPOWERED_CARD = -2146435039;
            public const int SCARD_W_RESET_CARD = -2146435038;
            public const int SCARD_W_REMOVED_CARD = -2146435037;

            /*===========================================================
            '   PROTOCOL
            '===========================================================*/
            public const int SCARD_PROTOCOL_UNDEFINED = 0x00;          // 
            public const int SCARD_PROTOCOL_T0 = 0x01;                 // T=0 
            public const int SCARD_PROTOCOL_T1 = 0x02;                 // T=1 
            public const int SCARD_PROTOCOL_RAW = 0x10000;             // Raw 
            public const int SCARD_UNKNOWN = 0;
            public const int SCARD_ABSENT = 1;
            public const int SCARD_PRESENT = 2;
            public const int SCARD_SWALLOWED = 3;
            public const int SCARD_POWERED = 4;
            public const int SCARD_NEGOTIABLE = 5;
            public const int SCARD_SPECIFIC = 6;


            /*==========================================================================
            ' Prototypes
            '==========================================================================*/


            [DllImport("winscard.dll")]
            public static extern int SCardEstablishContext(int dwScope, int pvReserved1, int pvReserved2, ref int phContext);

            [DllImport("winscard.dll")]
            public static extern int SCardReleaseContext(int phContext);

            [DllImport("winscard.dll")]
            public static extern int SCardConnect(int hContext, string szReaderName, int dwShareMode, int dwPrefProtocol, ref int phCard, ref int ActiveProtocol);

            [DllImport("winscard.dll")]
            public static extern int SCardBeginTransaction(int hCard);

            [DllImport("winscard.dll")]
            public static extern int SCardDisconnect(int hCard, int Disposition);

            [DllImport("winscard.dll")]
            public static extern int SCardListReaderGroups(int hContext, ref string mzGroups, ref int pcchGroups);

            [DllImport("winscard.DLL", EntryPoint = "SCardListReadersA", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
            public static extern int SCardListReaders(
                int hContext,
                byte[] Groups,
                byte[] Readers,
                ref int pcchReaders
                );
            [DllImport("winscard.dll")]
 public static extern int SCardStatus(int hCard, string szReaderName, ref int pcchReaderLen, ref int State, ref int Protocol, ref byte ATR, ref int ATRLen);
     [DllImport("winscard.dll")]
  public static extern int SCardEndTransaction(int hCard, int Disposition);

            [DllImport("winscard.dll")]
            public static extern int SCardState(int hCard, ref uint State, ref uint Protocol, ref byte ATR, ref uint ATRLen);

            [DllImport("WinScard.dll")]
            public static extern int SCardTransmit(IntPtr hCard,
                                                   ref SCARD_IO_REQUEST pioSendPci,
                                                   ref byte[] pbSendBuffer,
                                                   int cbSendLength,
                                                   ref SCARD_IO_REQUEST pioRecvPci,
                                                   ref byte[] pbRecvBuffer,
                                                   ref int pcbRecvLength);

            [DllImport("winscard.dll")]
            public static extern int SCardTransmit(int hCard, ref SCARD_IO_REQUEST pioSendRequest, ref byte SendBuff, int SendBuffLen, ref SCARD_IO_REQUEST pioRecvRequest, ref byte RecvBuff, ref int RecvBuffLen);

            [DllImport("winscard.dll")]
            public static extern int SCardTransmit(int hCard, ref SCARD_IO_REQUEST pioSendRequest, ref byte[] SendBuff, int SendBuffLen, ref SCARD_IO_REQUEST pioRecvRequest, ref byte[] RecvBuff, ref int RecvBuffLen);
            [DllImport("winscard.dll")]
            public static extern int SCardControl(int hCard, uint dwControlCode, ref byte SendBuff, int SendBuffLen, ref byte RecvBuff, int RecvBuffLen, ref int pcbBytesReturned);

            [DllImport("winscard.dll")]
            public static extern int SCardGetStatusChange(int hContext, int TimeOut, ref SCARD_READERSTATE ReaderState, int ReaderCount);

            public static string GetScardErrMsg(int ReturnCode)
            {
                switch (ReturnCode)
                {
                    case SCARD_E_CANCELLED:
                        return ("The action was canceled by an SCardCancel request.");
                    case SCARD_E_CANT_DISPOSE:
                        return ("The system could not dispose of the media in the requested manner.");
                    case SCARD_E_CARD_UNSUPPORTED:
                        return ("The smart card does not meet minimal requirements for support.");
                    case SCARD_E_DUPLICATE_READER:
                        return ("The reader driver didn't produce a unique reader name.");
                    case SCARD_E_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER:
                        return ("The data buffer for returned data is too small for the returned data.");
                    case SCARD_E_INVALID_ATR:
                        return ("An ATR string obtained from the registry is not a valid ATR string.");
                    case SCARD_E_INVALID_HANDLE:
                        return ("The supplied handle was invalid.");
                    case SCARD_E_INVALID_PARAMETER:
                        return ("One or more of the supplied parameters could not be properly interpreted.");
                    case SCARD_E_INVALID_TARGET:
                        return ("Registry startup information is missing or invalid.");
                    case SCARD_E_INVALID_VALUE:
                        return ("One or more of the supplied parameter values could not be properly interpreted.");
                    case SCARD_E_NOT_READY:
                        return ("The reader or card is not ready to accept commands.");
                    case SCARD_E_NOT_TRANSACTED:
                        return ("An attempt was made to end a non-existent transaction.");
                    case SCARD_E_NO_MEMORY:
                        return ("Not enough memory available to complete this command.");
                    case SCARD_E_NO_SERVICE:
                        return ("The smart card resource manager is not running.");
                    case SCARD_E_NO_SMARTCARD:
                        return ("The operation requires a smart card, but no smart card is currently in the device.");
                    case SCARD_E_PCI_TOO_SMALL:
                        return ("The PCI receive buffer was too small.");
                    case SCARD_E_PROTO_MISMATCH:
                        return ("The requested protocols are incompatible with the protocol currently in use with the card.");
                    case SCARD_E_READER_UNAVAILABLE:
                        return ("The specified reader is not currently available for use.");
                    case SCARD_E_READER_UNSUPPORTED:
                        return ("The reader driver does not meet minimal requirements for support.");
                    case SCARD_E_SERVICE_STOPPED:
                        return ("The smart card resource manager has shut down.");
                    case SCARD_E_SHARING_VIOLATION:
                        return ("The smart card cannot be accessed because of other outstanding connections.");
                    case SCARD_E_SYSTEM_CANCELLED:
                        return ("The action was canceled by the system, presumably to log off or shut down.");
                    case SCARD_E_TIMEOUT:
                        return ("The user-specified timeout value has expired.");
                    case SCARD_E_UNKNOWN_CARD:
                        return ("The specified smart card name is not recognized.");
                    case SCARD_E_UNKNOWN_READER:
                        return ("The specified reader name is not recognized.");
                    case SCARD_F_COMM_ERROR:
                        return ("An internal communications error has been detected.");
                    case SCARD_F_INTERNAL_ERROR:
                        return ("An internal consistency check failed.");
                    case SCARD_F_UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                        return ("An internal error has been detected, but the source is unknown.");
                    case SCARD_F_WAITED_TOO_LONG:
                        return ("An internal consistency timer has expired.");
                    case SCARD_S_SUCCESS:
                        return ("No error was encountered.");
                    case SCARD_W_REMOVED_CARD:
                        return ("The smart card has been removed, so that further communication is not possible.");
                    case SCARD_W_RESET_CARD:
                        return ("The smart card has been reset, so any shared state information is invalid.");
                    case SCARD_W_UNPOWERED_CARD:
                        return ("Power has been removed from the smart card, so that further communication is not possible.");
                    case SCARD_W_UNRESPONSIVE_CARD:
                        return ("The smart card is not responding to a reset.");
                    case SCARD_W_UNSUPPORTED_CARD:
                        return ("The reader cannot communicate with the card, due to ATR string configuration conflicts.");
                    default:
                        return ("?");
                }
            }
        }
```

that is all code i used
I made a connection with cardReader which returns my chip value when I set the chip to the device, in that case I used button1 as (show me chip ids). Now I just want to get that value I automatically trigger when I push the chip to the device that the method detects a new change and displays it in the textbox? is something like that possible?

Comment: In the constructor?  I don't know what you mean by "automatically".

Comment: @LarsTech I mean, whenever a method returns a string value to display in a textbox, I don't know if txtbox offers any option for that matter? Basically, I don't want to use a button to display a value, but when I open my window and when I scan a chip, it then registers a value, and then the method can return a value, in which case I would display the same value in a textbox. (by that I mean it automatically shows value)

Comment: I think OP wants something like a `PropertyChanged` notification. OP wants the Text in the textbox to automatically reflect the changed return value of `getcardUID()`

Comment: Dear @Mara, what causes the change of the return value of `getcardGUID()`? Raise an event when that happens and handle it and set the textbox.Text to the value you pass in your custom EventArgs implementation

Comment: What updates the output of `getcardGUID()` method?

Comment: You can automatically call the method at a designated interval with a `Timer`. To implement something like a callback or event to update the text automatically, we'll need to know more about the `connectCard()` and `getcardUID()` implementation.

Comment: *"when I open my window and when I scan a chip"* - those conditions should be easy to convert into a code. Open window - use form [Load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.load) event, *scan a chip* - is your custom action, you can add event there, rise it and use by this form as well.

Comment: @OguzOzgul I corrected the question, added some more information.

Comment: @PatrickTucci That sounds interesting, a callback function, for example, that it always returns a value if! = Null, eg with datetime.now to know exactly when the change occurred.

Comment: Since your `getcardUID()` always pulls the information (there is no notification from the device) you need to use a timer as suggested. Doesn't the card reader give you any events? Doesn't it in fact, implement the observer pattern?

Comment: If the device you're referring to raises WMI events when a chip is inserted or removed (similar to the events raised when a Pen drive is inserted or removed), you can try [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54298316/7444103), to update the UI with the result of the event notification (that code whatches for events raised by Win32_DiskDrive class devices, I don't know to what class yours belongs to).

Comment: @Jimi I think this is a good solution, only if you could call me this one DeviceChangedEvent

Comment: I don't think I understand what you asked. In that code, `DeviceChangedEvent` is a method delegate: it's called when the event is raised. It could be your `getcardUID()` method. Note that the event is raised in a ThreadPool Thread, so you need to `BeginInvoke()` the UI. That's all.

Comment: Your question is really about this Card Reader thing.  Document that better for your audience.

Comment: @Jimi I also added a class that I could recognize cardReader with.

Comment: That code is used to perform low level/direct access to the CardReader, since it uses IOCTL calls. It doesn't look like it provides change notifications, though. See if you can find to what WMI class it belongs to (if any). If it does provide WMI notifications, you should be able to get them. If it registers as an USB device of sort, that code could work as it is.

Comment: @Jimi i get the code change in the textbox but only when i call the method via the button, ie: every time i put the chip on the device and click on the button, then the code changes. all I need to do is call this function to be performed automatically if possible. ie changes from the chip are always displayed at a given time.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm talking about. IF the device raises WMI notifications when a chip is inserted, then you can receive the notification and automatically run the code you're now running clicking a Button. If this is what you actually want to do. If it's not, then I don't really know what you're asking.

Comment: @Jimi yes we understood each other then, this is what i want, how can i do it? can you help?

Comment: I already did that. I explained what you can do, how you can do it and provided code that does that exactly. Now, it's up to you to verify whether the device you have meets the criteria. I cannot do that for you. If it turns out that the device doesn't raise WMI notifications when a chip is inserted, then you have to poll it, with a Timer (you can use a threaded Timer here).

Comment: @Jimi yes thank you very much for your help, could you give me an example so that i can implement this with Threaded Timer?

Comment: See the example in the Docs that describes how a [System.Threading.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer) works. You can poll at 500ms.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Timer and add your work to it or you can create a seperate thread and run your method through that thread.
These links might be useful:

[Creating Threads C#](https://www.csharp-examples.net/create-new-thread/)

[Timers Class C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.8)