# Optimal way to get USB device connect / disconnect events from Windows service c#

Tags: c#, windows, service, usb

I'm trying to create a windows service to disable unwanted usb-devices and enable if it's allowed. To do so I need to monitor connect and disconnect events even for disabled devices.

Now I have the solution using wmi-events like this: `Select * from __InstanceCreationEvent within 2 where TargetISA 'Win32_PnPDevice'`. However it uses CPU a lot and in my opinion will bother users on weak PCs.

I heard about **WndProc** but as far as I understood it works only for programs with gui *(window)*, not for services.

All in all I need the event system that will not be such resource-intensive as wmi to avoid permanent CPU overload. I need only connect / disconnect events. It is not a problem to get full info about new / removed device.

Comment: Are you using a WQL event listener for this, of polling the state of all USB devices? See [How do I get information about recently connected USB device?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54298316/7444103)

Comment: @Jimi thx for your comment! If i use class '*Win32_DiskDrive*' as you mention in your answer - performance is OK. 

The problem is i need to get events on **disabled** devices as well. That's why i need to use class '*Win32_PnPDevice*' or '*CIM_LogicalDevice*'.  But when i use one of them my CPU gets permanent (*as program runs*) ~10% load. At weak PCs it will be ~20%.

Comment: Maybe, but that's not exactly what I was asking. The point is: are you using events (as shown in that code) or polling (i.e., using a Timer to query the state of devices)? If you're polling, switch to WQL events

Comment: Tried both methods. Events are little bit better in performance so I use events.