# How can I find parent/child relationships in USB devices with the C# ManagementObject object?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, wmi

I see in Windows device manager that a USB composite device has children, such as speaker/microphone/COM port.
How can I find these relations using the ManagementObject implementation in C# .NET?

I use following code to get the list:

```
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"Select * From Win32_PnPEntity");
ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();

foreach (var mo in collection)
{
    ManagementObject device = (ManagementObject)mo;

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    Console.WriteLine(device.Path);
    Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    Console.WriteLine("Properties:");
    Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------------------------");

    foreach (PropertyData o in device.Properties)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write(o.Name);
        Console.Write(" = ");

        if (o.IsArray && o.Value != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            string[] vals = (string[])o.Value;
            foreach (string ss in vals)
            {
                Console.Write("\t->");
                Console.Write(ss);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write(o.Value);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    Console.WriteLine("System Properties:");
    Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    foreach (PropertyData o in device.SystemProperties)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write(o.Name);
        Console.Write(" = ");

        if (o.IsArray && o.Value != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            string[] vals = (string[])o.Value;
            foreach (string ss in vals)
            {
                Console.Write("\t->");
                Console.Write(ss);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write(o.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

But still I cannot find the parent/child relationship as shown in device manager

I tried using the properties, but there is no such property as a parent.

Comment: You can probably get there using the [ASSOCIATORS OF Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/associators-of-statement) or the [REFERENCES OF Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/references-of-statement) (with an adeguate `RequiredQualifier` set) -- There's an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51806262/7444103 that uses `ASSOCIATORS OF` (with `AssocClass` set) to retrieve the endpoints associated with an USB drive device (in this case, the associated logical discs and associated partitions) -- You may need `REFERENCES OF`, though