# Automatically update dynamic variable in Winform text field

Tags: powershell, winforms

I would like to specify a variable in a text field in a winform. This should then update automatically in winform.
First, a WMI event is registered, which checks whether a USB device is connected or not. The result is stored in the $Global:ConnectionStatus variable.
This also works, the variable changes as soon as a USB device is connected or not. The initial entry of the status in Winform also works. Just don't update it.

Script:(Should work everywhere).

```
###Register event to watch changing usb drives

#Query for finding all device arrival events
$query = "SELECT * FROM Win32_VolumeChangeEvent WHERE EventType=2"       

#Register an event subscription
Register-WmiEvent -Query $query -Action {
    $volumeName = (Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID='$($Event.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.DriveName)'").VolumeName   
    $Global:ConnectionStatus = "Laufwerk $volumeName verbunden"
} | Out-Null            

#Query for finding all device Removal events
$query = "SELECT * FROM Win32_VolumeChangeEvent WHERE EventType=3"            

#Register an event subscription
Register-WmiEvent -Query $query -Action {
   $Global:ConnectionStatus = 'Nicht verbunden'
} | Out-Null

#region windows forms
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")
#
#Create main form
#
$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::FixedSingle #modifies the window border, not able to resize
$Form.Text = "Test"
$Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(946, 580)
$Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$Form.AutoScroll = $True
$Form.AutoSize = $True
$Form.AutoSizeMode = "GrowOnly" #GrowAndShrink or GrowOnly
$Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12)
$Form.Font = $Font
$Icon = [system.drawing.icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon($PSHOME + "\powershell.exe")
$Form.Icon = $Icon
#
#Create textbox
#
$Textbox1Connection = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'
$Textbox1Connection.Font = [System.Drawing.Font]::new('Microsoft Sans Serif', '9.75')
$Textbox1Connection.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(36, 45)
$Textbox1Connection.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(180, 22)
$Textbox1Connection.Text = "$Global:ConnectionStatus"
$textbox1Connection.TextAlign = 'Center'
$Textbox1Connection.ReadOnly = $True
$Form.Controls.Add($Textbox1Connection)

#Activate the form
$Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
[void]$Form.ShowDialog() 

#Unregister event
#Get-EventSubscriber | Unregister-Event
```

I tried
`$Textbox1Connection.add_TextChanged({ $displayLabel.Text = $Global:ConnectionStatus })` 
but that dosen`t work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to present a modal Dialog that is subsequently updated when WMI events notify of changes related to status of the local drives, you cannot execute the two parts in the same [Runspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspace).
The modal Dialog blocks the current Thread, so the notifications coming from the WMI events can only be accessed when the Dialog closes.

You can subscribe to these events in a different Runspace, and use a [Synchronized HashTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable.synchronized) (for example) to exchange data between runspaces.

- You can do the opposite, create the Form in a secondary Runspace. In this case, you have to explicitly set the [Runspace.ApartmentState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspace.apartmentstate) to `ApartmentState.STA` (single-threaded apartment), since some underlying Activex objects require this.

**Create the Form and add a TextBox Control to it:**
Note (1): I'm setting the Font of the Form. All child Controls, by default, inherit the Font from their direct Parents, hierarchically.
Note (2): The code is presented in separated parts, but it's of course the same script.
Note (3): The script uses the older [Register-WmiEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/register-wmievent), not available in PowerShell Core. When updating to PowerShell Core becomes necessary, see  [Register-CimIndicationEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/register-cimindicationevent)

```
using namespace System.Drawing
using namespace System.Windows.Forms

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

[Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
[Application]::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault($false)
Clear-Host

$form = [Form] @{
    ClientSize = [Point]::new(946, 580)
    Font = [Font]::new("Segoe UI", 9.75)   # Never use Microsoft Sans Serif
    FormBorderStyle = [FormBorderStyle]::FixedSingle
    Icon = [Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon($PSHOME + "\powershell.exe")
    StartPosition = [FormStartPosition]::CenterScreen
    Text = "Test"
}

$textboxConnection = [TextBox] @{
    Location = [Point]::new(36, 45)
    ReadOnly = $true
    Size = [Size]::new(300, 0) # Height auto-sizes to inherited Font height
    TextAlign = [HorizontalAlignment]::Center
}

$form.Controls.Add($textboxConnection)
$form.add_Shown({$form.Activate()})
```

Create a synchronized HashTable, using [Property-based access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-hashtable?view=powershell-7.4#property-based-access).
I'm storing references to the Form and the child TextBox here

```
$hash = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})
$hash.Value = ""
$hash.Window = $form
$hash.TextBox = $textboxConnection
```

Create a second Runspace (somewhat verbose) and add a script that subscribes to the WMI events (see [RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspacefactory.createrunspace) and [PowerShell.Create()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.create) for more details).

When an event is raised, the script calls a local function that updates the content of the TextBox. Since we're in a cross-Thread scenario, we need to marshal the call to the Thread the window belongs to.
Here, I'm using the reference to the Form previously stored in the HashTable, to call is [BeginInvoke()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke) method, which invokes the standard dispatcher asynchronously (we cannot block event handlers in any way).
The Action delegate sets the Text property of the TextBox to the new value.

```
$iss = [InitialSessionState]::CreateDefault2()
$runspace = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspace($iss)
$runspace.Open()
$runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("hash", $hash)

$shell = [PowerShell]::Create($iss)
$shell.Runspace = $runspace
$shell.AddScript({
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Win32_VolumeChangeEvent WHERE EventType=2"       
    Register-WmiEvent -Query $query -Action {
        $volumeName = (Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID='$($Event.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.DriveName)'").VolumeName
        $hash.Value = "Laufwerk $volumeName verbunden"
        Update-Window
    } | Out-Null

    $query = "SELECT * FROM Win32_VolumeChangeEvent WHERE EventType=3"            
    Register-WmiEvent -Query $query -Action {
        $hash.Value = "Nicht verbunden"
        Update-Window
    } | Out-Null

    Function Update-Window {  # You can of course pass the text as a parameter
        $hash.Window.BeginInvoke([action]{
            $hash.TextBox.Text = $hash.Value
        })
    }
}) | Out-Null  # When the session terminates, the subscriptions are canceled

$runspaceHandle = $shell.BeginInvoke()
[void]$form.ShowDialog()

$shell.EndInvoke($runspaceHandle)
$runspace.Close()
$shell.Dispose()
```

---

You can also use a Timer to poll the `$hash.Value`.
Probably less efficient and it may cause some flickering, but it works anyway.

```
# [...]
$timer = [Timer] @{ Interval = 250 }
# No need to BeginInvoke() here
$timer.add_Tick({$textboxConnection.Text = $hash.Value})
# [...]
$form.add_Shown({$form.Activate(); $timer.Start()})
$form.add_FormClosed({$timer.Dispose()})
# [...]
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, that works great and looks much more professional than what I've found meanwhile. I will use this way in the future!
Except for one point about which I "lied" before.
During the initial call, the status is not displayed correctly in the text field. It is emty! (I always had the variable available in the PS ISE while my test, so I was wrong). This doesn't work your way either. I have a "botched" solution that works like your second way with a timer. Before that, however, I have to determine and enter the initial status of the drive.

Comment: Well, of course the initial status is undetermined, if you don't query it beforehand. The updates are based on events, raised when *something happens*. When the script is first run, nothing has happened yet. Make a query (in the main runspace) to check the status of the drive, then initialize `$hash.Value` to that value instead of an empty string. This assumes you're monitoring a volume with a specific name (`Caption`), `Model` or `SerialNumber` and its `MediaLoaded` property is set to `true`

Comment: This may be helpful: [Get the serial number of USB storage devices in .Net Core 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51806262/7444103) (not just about the serial number, as you an see) -- You could also make a query that checks whether any drive with `InterfaceType = 'USB'` is inserted at that time. I don't know what you're actually monitoring

Answer (score 0):

My own, "potched" way:

```
    function TextBox-Update
{
  $Textbox1Connection.Text = "$Global:ConnectionStatus"
}


#Get acual status, name and driveletter of usb device
$MP3PlayerConnected = Get-disk | Where-Object bustype -eq 'usb' | Where-Object {$_.FriendlyName -like 'FC-1307 SD*'} | get-partition | get-volume 
if ($MP3PlayerConnected.FileSystemLabel -like 'Rock')
{
  $Global:ConnectionStatus = "Laufwerk" + " " + $MP3PlayerConnected.DriveLetter + ":" + " " + "verbunden"
}
else
{
  $Global:ConnectionStatus = 'Nicht verbunden'
}


###Register event to watch changing usb drives

#Query for finding all device arrival events
$query = "SELECT * FROM Win32_VolumeChangeEvent WHERE EventType=2"       

#Register an event subscription
Register-WmiEvent -Query $query -Action {
    $volumeName = (Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID='$($Event.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.DriveName)'").VolumeName   
    $Global:ConnectionStatus = "Laufwerk $volumeName verbunden"
} | Out-Null            

#Query for finding all device Removal events
$query = "SELECT * FROM Win32_VolumeChangeEvent WHERE EventType=3"            

#Register an event subscription
Register-WmiEvent -Query $query -Action {
   $Global:ConnectionStatus = 'Nicht verbunden'
} | Out-Null

#region windows forms
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")
#
#Create main form
#
$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::FixedSingle #modifies the window border, not able to resize
$Form.Text = "Test"
$Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(946, 580)
$Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$Form.AutoScroll = $True
$Form.AutoSize = $True
$Form.AutoSizeMode = "GrowOnly" #GrowAndShrink or GrowOnly
$Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12)
$Form.Font = $Font
$Icon = [system.drawing.icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon($PSHOME + "\powershell.exe")
$Form.Icon = $Icon
#
#Create textbox
#
$Textbox1Connection = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'
$Textbox1Connection.Font = [System.Drawing.Font]::new('Microsoft Sans Serif', '9.75')
$Textbox1Connection.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(36, 45)
$Textbox1Connection.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(180, 22)
$Textbox1Connection.Text = "$Global:ConnectionStatus"
$textbox1Connection.TextAlign = 'Center'
$Textbox1Connection.ReadOnly = $True
$Form.Controls.Add($Textbox1Connection)
#
#Create timer to update texbox over fuction TextBox-Update
#
$Timer = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Timer
$Timer.Interval = 2000
$Timer.Add_Tick({TextBox-Update})
$Timer.Enabled = $True

#Activate the form
$Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
[void]$Form.ShowDialog() 

#Unregister event
#Get-EventSubscriber | Unregister-Event
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).