# Problems with WMI query format with the ManagementObjectSearcher

Tags: c#, wmi

I've got a WMI query here that wont work for some reason, the documentation around it isn't great and I've got

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive
```

working as a query to the `ManagementObjectSearcher`. But this returns information about all the drives connected to a system, I just wish to get information about a single specified drive connected to the system.

Here is the code for the searcher to retrieve information about a specific drive:

```
string GetPhysicalDriveNumber(string driveLetter)
{
    DriveInfo driveInfo = new DriveInfo(driveLetter);

    if (driveInfo.DriveType == DriveType.Fixed)
    {
        // If it's a fixed drive, query WMI to get the physical drive number
        using (ManagementObjectSearcher UNC_searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher($"SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE DeviceID LIKE '%{driveLetter.Substring(0, 1)}%'"))
        {
            foreach (ManagementObject drive in UNC_searcher.Get())
            {
                // Extract the physical drive number from the DeviceID
                string deviceID = drive["DeviceID"].ToString();

                return deviceID;
            }
        }
    }

    return null; // Return -1 if it's not a fixed drive or if the physical drive number is not found
}

string query = $"SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE DeviceID = {GetPhysicalDriveNumber("C")}";

var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);

Console.WriteLine("WMI QUERY IS : "+ query);

foreach (ManagementObject disk in searcher.Get())
{
    string model = disk["Model"].ToString();
    string manufacturer = disk["Manufacturer"].ToString();
    string serialNumber = disk["SerialNumber"].ToString();

    Console.WriteLine("NVMe SSD Information:");
    Console.WriteLine($"Model: {model}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Manufacturer: {manufacturer}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Serial Number: {serialNumber}");

    string deviceId = disk["DeviceID"]?.ToString();

    Console.WriteLine($"DEVICE ID ={deviceId}");
}
```

Here are some screenshots of what the console shows:

[the console showing the WMI query is invalid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qZwu.png)

I've tried using `WHERE DeviceID = \\.\PHYSICALDRIVEX`, `X` being the number of the drive in the system, but it doesn't work and I get an "invalid query" error.

Comment: `"... WHERE DeviceID = '\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0'"` -- The query in `GetPhysicalDriveNumber()` tries to match `DeviceID` to `C`, which of course won't get any result. See [the code in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51806262/7444103). Note that `Win32_DiskDrivePhysicalMedia` and `Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition` are [associators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/associators-of-statement), so probably you want to use `Win32_LogicalDisk` in `GetPhysicalDriveNumber()` (so you may want to rename that method, e.g., `GetLogicalDriveByID()`)

Comment: As shown in the previous comment , surround the _DeviceID_ with single quotes (in an SQL query string values are surrounded with quotes) and escape each backslash by adding another backslash. Alternatively, instead of escaping each backslash with another backslash, you could try using `$@` instead of just `$`.